FrameTicks too small
The frame ticks here appear to be realy small. especially when it comes to minor ticks..

What I want is this:

I have used the same code for these two graphs, but the outcome is different:
, FrameStyle -> 
 Directive[Black, 
  Thickness[0.002]], FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {All, Automatic}},

I also used "TickLength" but it did not work.

I'm not entirely sure, but I think you might need to come up with an entire tick specification yourself. Something like this.
verticalRightTicksMinor = Table[{y, y, .02}, {y, -1, 1, .2}];
verticalRightTicksMajor = Table[{y, y, .04}, {y, -1, 1}];

Plot[
  Cos[x], 
  {x, 0, 10}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, verticalRightTicks}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
  FrameTicksStyle -> {{Automatic, Directive[Orange, Thickness[.01]]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]



Thanks,
none works for me. the only thing I could do was to decrease the image size and it was fixed. Thanks anyway. @lericr
